# Django bulk create objects from QuerySet

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

If I have a `QuerySet` created from the following command:

```
data = ModelA.objects.values('date').annotate(total=Sum('amount'), average=Avg('amount'))
# <QuerySet [{'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 15, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total': 19982.0, 'average': 333.03333333333336}, {'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 15, 0, 30, tzinfo=<UTC>), 'total': 18389.0, 'average': 306.48333333333335}]>
```

Is it possible to use `data` to create `ModelB`objects from each hash inside the `QuerySet`?

I realize I could iterate and unpack the `QuerySet` and do it like so:

```
   for q in data:
        ModelB.objects.create(date=q['date'], total=q['total'], average=q['average'])
```

But is there a more elegant way? It seems redundant to iterate and create when they're almost in the `bulk_create` format.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is more efficient than your call because it uses `bulk_create`, which invokes just one SQL bulk create operation, as opposed to one create per object; also, it is much more elegant:

```
ModelB.objects.bulk_create([ ModelB(**q) for q in data ])
```

As to how this works, the double asterisk unpacks a dictionary (or dictionary-like object) into keyword arguments to a Python function.

Official Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create

Comment: I think this will be more efficient, cause in the for-loop 'create' will trigger save for each element, but for bulk_create there's will be only one sql;